# What methods do you use to compress your pdfs using PyMuPDF that maximize the balance between quality, size, and speed?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, compression, pymupdf

Here is what I came up with and I would like to know what others are doing to maximize the balance between compression and quality.

```
import fitz  #Installed via PyMuPDF. PyCharm sometimes doesn't recognize this import, however code still runs.
# https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/the-basics.html#extract-text-from-a-pdf

def compress_pdf(input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path, colorspace=fitz.csRGB, garbage=3, dpi=72):  # Working, however size is about the same.
    """Compresses a PDF file using PyMuPDF (AKA fitz).
    Args:
        input_pdf_path: The path to the input PDF file.
        output_pdf_path: The path to the output PDF file.

    https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.get_pixmap
    colorspace:
        fitz.csRGB
        fitz.csGRAY
        fitz.csCMYK

    https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document.save
    garbage:
        0 = none
        1 = remove unused (unreferenced) objects.
        2 = in addition to 1, compact the xref table.
        3 = in addition to 2, merge duplicate objects.
        4 = in addition to 3, check stream objects for duplication. This may be slow.
    """
    # Open the input PDF file.
    doc = fitz.Document(input_pdf_path)
    doc_new = fitz.Document()
    for page in doc:
        pixmap = page.get_pixmap(colorspace=colorspace, dpi=dpi, annots=False)
        new_page = doc_new.new_page(-1)
        xref = new_page.insert_image(rect=new_page.bound(), pixmap=pixmap)

    doc_new.save(output_pdf_path, garbage=garbage, deflate=True, deflate_images=True, deflate_fonts=True, pretty=True)
    doc.close()
    doc_new.close()
```

I also tried using ghostcript which works, however it is slower and I was not able to get the window to completely disappear.

Comment: PyCharm is known to have bugs here. Do or check the installation in a terminal window, and you will see, that everything is in order. Otherwise, a good balance when saving delivers `garbage=3, deflate=True`. The short form `doc.ez_save(...)` does exactly that. Using `clean=True` is actually never required - although it sounds so nice . All that only applies, if you do not save incrementally of course.